# How to optymalize Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have problem with optymalize saving data to Database via EntityFramework.
In my ASP.NET MVC Web App. I'm loading data from CSV File, with 86 000 records, which every has 200 columns. Then foreach row i'm making obj with 900 properites, because the records have a lot of properties which i need to convert it to bits. I tried to saved after 5k, 10k, 20k. The best running time is 1 hour and 15 minutes, without saving intermediate. For 40k records time is 15 minutes.

Here is my c# code:

```cs
if (ModelValidate())
            {​
                List<CA190_TESTWO> cA190_TESTWOs = new List<CA190_TESTWO>();
 
                bool ListIsNotEmpty = IsAnyRecordInList(cA190_TESTWOs);
                if (ListIsNotEmpty)
                {​
                    var lastCA = bWDiagnosticEntities.CA190_TESTWO.Max(x => x.ID);
                    Start_Counter = lastCA;
                }​
                else
                {​
                    Start_Counter = 1;
                }​
 
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {​
                    fileInput.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                    {​
                        var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        {​
                            Delimiter = ";",
                            HasHeaderRecord = false
                        }​;
                        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig))
                        {​
                            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Read>().ToList();
                            foreach (var record in records)
                            {​
                                Start_Counter++;
                                counter++;
                                int ParM = int.Parse(record.ParM);
                                BitArray SupportSettings1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParM }​ );
                                int ParN = int.Parse(record.ParN);
                                BitArray SupportSettings2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParN }​);
                                int ParO = int.Parse(record.ParO);
                                BitArray SupportSettings3 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParO }​);
                                int ParP = int.Parse(record.ParP);
                                BitArray SupportSettings4 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParP }​);
                                int ParW = int.Parse(record.ParW);
                                BitArray CommunicationStatus1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParW }​);
                                int ParX = int.Parse(record.ParX);
                                BitArray CommunicationStatus2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParX }​);
                                int ParY = int.Parse(record.ParY);
                                BitArray CommunicationError1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParY }​);
                                int ParZ = int.Parse(record.ParZ);
                                BitArray CommunicationError2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParZ }​);
                                int ParAA = int.Parse(record.ParAA);
                                BitArray CommunicationError3 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAA }​);
                                int ParAB = int.Parse(record.ParAB);
                                BitArray CommunicationError4 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAB }​);
                                int ParAC = int.Parse(record.ParAC);
                                BitArray CommunicationError5 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAC }​);
                                int ParAD = int.Parse(record.ParAD);
                                BitArray CommunicationError6 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAD }​);
                                int ParAE = int.Parse(record.ParAE);
                                BitArray CommunicationError7 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAE }​);
                                int ParAF = int.Parse(record.ParAF);
                                BitArray CommunicationError8 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAF }​);
                                int ParAG = int.Parse(record.ParAG);
                                BitArray CommunicationError9 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAG }​);
                                int ParAH = int.Parse(record.ParAH);
                                BitArray CommunicationError10 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAH }​);
                                int ParAI = int.Parse(record.ParAI);
                                BitArray CommunicationError11 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAI }​);
                                int ParAJ = int.Parse(record.ParAJ);
                                BitArray CommunicationError12 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAJ }​);
                                int ParAO = int.Parse(record.ParAO);
                                BitArray Stats1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAO }​);
                                int ParAP = int.Parse(record.ParAP);
                                BitArray Stats2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAP }​);
                                int ParAQ = int.Parse(record.ParAQ);
                                BitArray Stats3 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAQ }​);
                                int ParAW = int.Parse(record.ParAW);
                                BitArray StatsCan1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAW }​);
                                int ParAY = int.Parse(record.ParAY);
                                BitArray StatsCan2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParAY }​);
                                int ParBA = int.Parse(record.ParBA);
                                BitArray PPR = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBA }​);
                                int ParBC = int.Parse(record.ParBC);
                                BitArray InDig = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBC }​);
                                int ParBD = int.Parse(record.ParBD);
                                BitArray OutDig = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBD }​);
                                int ParBE = int.Parse(record.ParBE);
                                BitArray BWZA_IN = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBE }​);
                                int ParBF = int.Parse(record.ParBF);
                                BitArray BWZA_OUT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBF }​);
                                int ParBG = int.Parse(record.ParBG);
                                BitArray CABA_IN = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBG }​);
                                int ParBH = int.Parse(record.ParBH);
                                BitArray CABA_OUT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBH }​);
                                int ParBI = int.Parse(record.ParBI);
                                BitArray CABB_IN = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBI }​);
                                int ParBJ = int.Parse(record.ParBJ);
                                BitArray CABB_OUT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBJ }​);
                                int ParBK = int.Parse(record.ParBK);
                                BitArray BWSO_IN = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBK }​);
                                int ParBL = int.Parse(record.ParBL);
                                BitArray BWSO_OUT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBL }​);
                                int ParBX = int.Parse(record.ParBX);
                                BitArray STATSFAL1 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParBX }​);
                                int ParCF = int.Parse(record.ParCF);
                                BitArray STATSFAL2 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParCF }​);
                                int ParCN = int.Parse(record.ParCN);
                                BitArray STATSFAL3 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParCN }​);
                                int ParCV = int.Parse(record.ParCV);
                                BitArray STATSFAL4 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParCV }​);
                                int ParDD = int.Parse(record.ParDD);
                                BitArray STATSFAL5 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParDD }​);
                                int ParDL = int.Parse(record.ParDL);
                                BitArray STATSFAL6 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParDL }​);
                                int ParDT = int.Parse(record.ParDT);
                                BitArray STATSFAL7 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParDT }​);
                                int ParEB = int.Parse(record.ParEB);
                                BitArray STATSFAL8 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParEB }​);
                                int ParEJ = int.Parse(record.ParEJ);
                                BitArray STATSFAL9 = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParEJ }​);
                                int ParEK = int.Parse(record.ParEK);
                                BitArray AKUSTAT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParEK }​);
                                int ParFK = int.Parse(record.ParFK);
                                BitArray BMSSTAT = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParFK }​);
                                int ParFL = int.Parse(record.ParFL);
                                BitArray BMSSTATLAD = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParFL }​);
                                int ParGB = int.Parse(record.ParGB);
                                BitArray CHARGERSTATS = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParGB }​);
                                int ParGK = int.Parse(record.ParGK);
                                BitArray BWMRE_STATS = new BitArray(new int[] {​ ParGK }​);
                                //for (int i = 0; i < SupportSettings1.Length; i++)
                                //{​
                                //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SupportSettings1[i]);
                                //}​
                                string date = record.Day + "-" + record.Month + "-" + record.Year + " " + record.Hour + ":" + record.Min + ":" + record.Second;
                                DateTime recordDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                                //var IsAnyElementWithTheSameDate = bWDiagnosticEntities.CA190_TESTWO.Where(x => x.Date == recordDate).FirstOrDefault();                             
                                //if (DateVerification(record, IsAnyElementWithTheSameDate))
                                //{​
                                    CA190_TESTWO newCAObj = new CA190_TESTWO();
                                    newCAObj.ID = Start_Counter;
                                    newCAObj.Date = recordDate;
                                    newCAObj.Machine_ID = int.Parse(record.ParG);
                                    newCAObj.Machine_Type = int.Parse(record.ParH);
                                    newCAObj.Manipulator_Setting = int.Parse(record.ParI);

                                    ... HERE IS over 900 properties ... 
   
                                    newCAObj.booking200 = int.Parse(record.ParGR);
 

                                    bWDiagnosticEntities.CA190_TESTWO.Add(newCAObj);
                                if (counter >= 20000)
                                {​
                                    bWDiagnosticEntities.BulkSaveChangesAsync();
                                    counter = 0;
                                }​
                                //}​
 
                            }​
                        }​
                    }​
                }​
            }​
            bWDiagnosticEntities.BulkSaveChangesAsync();
            return View();
```

Comment: If your quest is to boost performance, the first thing to do is to find out what is the biggest cost in performance. So, you need to profile, profile, profile. Then you can identify where you "lose" most of the time. Then you can break that out into a benchmark, improve it and reintegrate. Then restart the cycle. Maybe you also need to think about data layout. 900 cols is humongous (IMHO). You may want to streamline that a little, because I guess, you'll find a lot of performance is lost in Parsing/Converting ...

Comment: @Fildor I did test. I removed save it to DB, just to new object list, and the this proces durning 2 seconds.

Comment: Good start, so inserting to the DB is slow. I'd expect that. As I said, I'd expect that you can achieve performance boosts in streamlining the table structure. But that's a guess on my part. If I were to do it, I'd try to prove it.

Comment: @Fildor The structure of the tabel is:  80% of 900 properties is bites, rest are ints and one datetime. The problem is that i couldn't "slim down" db structure, because these are parameters from real machine like voltage, current etc... The next step will be try to did the same db in Sql Standard Version. Could it boost performance?

Comment: I really do not see why you need every bit as a separate column in db and I really think this slows you down _a lot_. Switching DB Engines of course also will change runtime. Some Engines are better at different things than others. Those differences _can_ cancel each other out, so switching the engine _can_ have an impact, doesn't need to. But may also lead to shift focus of optimizations to other things...

Comment: @Fildor I thought that the better option is to save bits to db and then only read bit for example on position 620. Finally i would like to make reports where i would list the bit where is true in some while. In your opinion and experience, the better way is to fragment int to bits durning saving proces to db or fragment to bits on every call method?

Comment: In my experience it is better to stuff bits together when persisting them. You can (should be able to) still apply bitmasks later. I am reading in this very moment, MS SQL Server will even optimize bit columns into bytes for you ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your help and knowledge. I will do it like u said and then I will write here result of this. I would like to stay in touch with you.

Comment: I would probably also have to do a little "trial and error" approach here. Just make sure, you measure if your changes have actually had a positive effect. Sure, as long a you @ me, I'll get notified.

Comment: @Fildor I did that like you said. That i'm sending only 200 properties to db a the operation time is the same.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I guess then you'll have to profile and find the culprit.

Comment: @Fildor I got solution. I set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false and proces is during 20 seconds!